# purrr map equivalent of nested for loop

Tags: r, purrr

What is the purrr::map equivalent of:

```
for (i in 1:4) {
  for (j in 1:6) {
    print(paste(i, j, sep = "-"))
  }
}
```

OR

```
lapply(1:4, function(i) 
  lapply(1:6, function(j) 
    print(paste(i, j, sep = "-"))))
```

Conceptually, what I'm not getting is how to refer to the *outer* loop in the *inner* map function.

```
map(1:4, ~ map(1:6, ~ print(paste(.x, ????, sep = "-")))
```

Comment: `outer(1:4, 1:6, paste, sep = '-')` gives a nice matrix. `cross2(1:4, 1:6) %>% map_chr(paste, collapse = '-')` gives a character vector.

Comment: or in base for a character vector, `do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(1:4, 1:6), sep = '-'))`

Comment: I find it improves readability to use `%>%` between consecutive `purrr` map-like functions. E.i pass the output list of one map as the input list to another map function.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As @r2evans points out, the `.x` from your first call is masked. however you can create a lambda function that takes 2 parameters `.x` and `.y`, and assign the previous `.x` to the new `.y` through the `...` argument.

I'll use `walk` rather than `map` as in this case you're only interested in side effects (printing)

```
walk(1:4,~ walk(1:6, ~ print(paste(.x, .y, sep = "-")),.y=.x))
```

Another option is to use `expand.grid` to lay out the combinations, and then iterate on those with `pwalk` (or `pmap` in other circumstances)

```
purrr::pwalk(expand.grid(1:4,1:6),~print(paste(.x, .y, sep = "-")))
```

Output in both cases:

```
[1] "1-1"
[1] "2-1"
[1] "3-1"
[1] "4-1"
[1] "5-1"
[1] "6-1"
[1] "1-2"
[1] "2-2"
[1] "3-2"
[1] "4-2"
[1] "5-2"
[1] "6-2"
[1] "1-3"
[1] "2-3"
[1] "3-3"
[1] "4-3"
[1] "5-3"
[1] "6-3"
[1] "1-4"
[1] "2-4"
[1] "3-4"
[1] "4-4"
[1] "5-4"
[1] "6-4"
```

Answer (score 47):

The use of [function formulas (`~`)](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html#arguments) is a little limited when trying to nest like this, since it is perfectly unclear which level of `map` you are attempting to reference. (Well, that's not correct. It's perfectly clear to me that it is referencing *inside-out*, and since they both use the same nomenclature, the outer variables are being masked by the inner variables.)

I think your best way around it is to not use the formula method, instead using immediate/anonymous (or predefined) functions:

```
library(purrr)
str(map(1:2, function(x) map(1:3, function(y) paste(x, y, sep = "-"))))
# List of 2
#  $ :List of 3
#   ..$ : chr "1-1"
#   ..$ : chr "1-2"
#   ..$ : chr "1-3"
#  $ :List of 3
#   ..$ : chr "2-1"
#   ..$ : chr "2-2"
#   ..$ : chr "2-3"
```

Comment: You could also quote one and pass the function name and arguments separately for the other: `map(1:4, ~map_chr(1:6, paste, .x, sep = '-'))`

Comment: Good point, works much better when one of the levels can be literal. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Just Running through this now.

```
walk(1:4,~ walk(1:6, ~ print(paste(.x, .y, sep = "-")),.y=.x)) 
[1] "1-1"
[1] "2-1"
[1] "3-1"
[1] "4-1"
[1] "5-1"
[1] "6-1"
[1] "1-2"
```

and

```
purrr::pwalk(expand.grid(1:4,1:6),~print(paste(.x, .y, sep = "-")))
[1] "1-1"
[1] "2-1"
[1] "3-1"
[1] "4-1"
[1] "1-2"
```

but to match your nested for loops exactly it fiddled and this works.

```
for (i in 1:4) {
  for (j in 1:6) {
    print(paste(i, j, sep = "-"))
  }
}
[1] "1-1"
[1] "1-2"
[1] "1-3"
[1] "1-4"
[1] "1-5"
[1] "1-6"
[1] "2-1"

purrr::pwalk(expand.grid(1:6,1:4),~print(paste(.y, .x, sep = "-")))
[1] "1-1"
[1] "1-2"
[1] "1-3"
[1] "1-4"
[1] "1-5"
[1] "1-6"
[1] "2-1"

#or even a map of this
walk(1:4,~ walk(1:6, ~ print(paste(.y, .x, sep = "-")),.y=.x))
```

I have yet to figure out why the `.y=.x` is at the end though.

Comment: I think it might be a fluke that it works. My speculation is that creating a function with `~` looks for possible recognized arguments (`.`, `.x`, `.y`, `..1`, etc.) and the last argument (`.y=.x`) is somehow aliasing what was `.x` in the outer walk is being set to `.y` in the inner walk. You can replace `.y` with `..1`, but not with other variables.

Comment: Using the formula notation is like creating a function of form `function (..., .x = ..1, .y = ..2, . = ..1)  {}`, so you can pass an arg to `.y` through the `walk` call, and you can pass it the `.x` of the outer walk call since it's not overriden by anything at this point, not a fluke!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an addition to the already very good answers and answer-comments.  I wanted to make a single purr-like function that accomplishes the OP's goals.  So I made a `loop_map` function that behaves analogously to the main Purrr `map` functions.

```
loop_map <- function(why, ecks, fun) {
  
  # 2: for every call of this (the previous .f) the new .f is called for each
  # value of ecks, supplied the same value of why each time
  iterate_over_x = function(x_in,y_in,fun_in){
    return(pmap(.l = list(x = x_in), .f = fun_in ,y = y_in ) %>%
 set_names(nm = as.character(x_in))) 
  }
  
  # 1: this ".f"  argument is called once for each element of why, and is 
  # supplied one value of why and every value of ecks each time
  pmap(.l = list(y_in = why), .f = iterate_over_x, x_in = ecks, fun_in = fun) %>% 
set_names(nm = as.character(why))
  
}



my_paste <- function(x,y) {
  paste(x,y)
}



loop_map(list("a","b"),list("c","d"),my_paste)
```

As a bonus I named the output so that one can index it more easily, or somehow convert it to a dataframe.  I would like to improve this function by adding capabilities to loop over arbitrarily many input lists, and possibly to use functions that take `...` arguments (right now everything has to be named).   If anyone has an idea for how to do this feel free to let me know.