# Replacing the for loop by the map() function to speed up

Tags: r

I create a list called list_ok:

```
 list_ok <- list()
 a=c(1,2,3,4,5)
 b=c(6,7,8,9,10)
 c=c(11,12,13,14,15)
 d=c(16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
 e=c(21,22,23,24,25)

 list_ok[[1]]=a
 list_ok[[2]]=b
 list_ok[[3]]=c
 list_ok[[4]]=d
 list_ok[[5]]=e
```

This code below, creates the same list_ok by using a `for loop`:

```
new_list <- vector(mode = "list", length=5)

for (i in 1:5) {
  for(k in 1:5) {     
    new_list[[i]][k] <- list_ok[[i]][k]
  }
}

> new_list
```

How can I do the same exercise using the map function? My problem is to know how to deal with the two different indexes (`i` and `k`) in map function.

I will use the same idea in another exercise wich is more complex.

Any help?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. `new_list` and `list_ok` are identical. Why do you want to create an identical copy of a `list` with a `for` loop (or with `purrr::map`)? This sounds like an XY problem to me. Can you provide a few more details?

Comment: Its just an exercise. Its to simple, I just want to replace the for code by the map function. Its another way of doing the same thing.

Comment: I still don't understand; `new_list <- map(list_ok, I)` would create an identical copy of `ok_list`. But in that case why not just `new_list <- list_ok`?

Comment: @MauritsEvers my iidea is to know how to work with map functions with 2 different indexes as the for command above.

Comment: You're thinking about this the wrong way. The advantage of `map` is that it allows for vectorised functions, i.e. loop throw the elements of a `list` and then apply a vectorised function on its elements. Thinking about this in terms of 2 "array" indices is the wrong way to think about `map` (or `*apply` for that matter), and you end up with convoluted solutions like the ones presented below. If you must use array indices, use a `for` loop; there is nothing wrong with `for` loops in R, provided you use them correctly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `lapply` and `sapply` with the `parallel` package to speed up?

```
library(parallel)

numCores <- detectCores()
cl = makeCluster(numCores)

parLapply(list_ok, function(x)
  sapply(x, function(y) y), cl = cl)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll find this Q&A useful: [purrr map equivalent of nested for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847613/purrr-map-equivalent-of-nested-for-loop)

For loops within loops, the easiest thing is to create an anonymous function as the second argument for `map` and within that anonymous function use `map` again (in this case I'm using `map_dbl`) with another anonymous function where you can combine one level of loop (x) with another level of loop (y).

```
library(purrr)

map(list_ok, function(x) map_dbl(seq_along(list_ok), function(y) x[[y]]))

[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[2]]
[1]  6  7  8  9 10

[[3]]
[1] 11 12 13 14 15

[[4]]
[1] 16 17 18 19 20

[[5]]
[1] 21 22 23 24 25
```