# Nested tabset with rmarkdown and purrr::walk2

Tags: r, r-markdown, purrr

I am trying to create a nested tabset ideally using `purrr::walk2`. But something is missing in how I am creating the tabsets as the h2 tabs aren't joining. Here is a rmd reprex. Any way to do this in rmarkdown?

````
---
title: "nested-tabs"
output: html_document
date: "2022-08-25"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(glue)

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r}
starwars <- starwars %>% 
  head(5)

levels <- starwars %>% 
  distinct(sex, homeworld)
```

# Messy output 
```{r results='asis'}
walk2(levels$sex, levels$homeworld, ~{
    cat(
    glue(
      "\n## <<.x>> {.tabset}",
      .open = "<<",
      .close = ">>"
    ),
    "\n"
  )
  
  cat(glue("\n### {.y}"), "\n")
  
  starwars %>% 
    filter(sex == .x, homeworld == .y)
})
```

# Desired output
```{r results='asis'}
walk(levels$sex, ~{
    cat(
    glue(
      "\n## <<.x>> {.tabset}",
      .open = "<<",
      .close = ">>"
    ),
    "\n"
  )
  
  sw_tmp <- starwars %>% 
    filter(sex == .x)
  
  walk(levels$homeworld, ~{
  cat(glue("\n### {.x}"), "\n")
  
  starwars %>% 
    filter(homeworld == .x)
  })
})
```
````

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `purrr::walk2()` is not equivalent to two nested `purrr::walk()`s. See this small example for instance:

```r
library(purrr)

walk(c("A", "B"), ~{
  print(paste(.x, "---"))
  walk(1:2, ~{
    print(paste(.x, "-"))
  })
})
#> [1] "A ---"
#> [1] "1 -"
#> [1] "2 -"
#> [1] "B ---"
#> [1] "1 -"
#> [1] "2 -"

walk2(c("A", "B"), c(1:2), ~{
  print(paste(.x, "---"))
  print(paste(.y, "-"))
})
#> [1] "A ---"
#> [1] "1 -"
#> [1] "B ---"
#> [1] "2 -"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

`walk2()` takes the first element of `.x` and `.y` for the first iteration, the second element of `.x` and `.y` for the second iteration, etc. This is why only one tab appears in your "messy" section.

You can't just replace the nested `walk()` (or nested `for` loops) with `walk2()`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847613/purrr-map-equivalent-of-nested-for-loop) are some solutions on how to replace these nested loops with `purrr`, but I think that the solution you already have is clean enough compared to them.