# find the maximum value in a subset of columns, in a nested list

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a list which is structured like this:

```
examplelist<- lst
(n1=tibble(letter= letters[1:10], week=c(100,200,300,400,500,1,2,3,4,5), rowcount=1:10),
n2=tibble(letter= letters[11:20], week=c(100,200,300,400,500,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5),rowcount=1:10))
```

I want to use the map function to find the maximum value in the last 5 rows of each week column.

I have tried these two appraoches, but they don't work

```
maxweek <- map_dbl(examplelist,~subset(.,rowcount >5),~max(.[["week"]],na.rm = TRUE))
maxweek <- map_dbl(examplelist,~max(.[["week"]],subset=rowcount >5,na.rm = TRUE))
```

I get an error:
Error in `map_dbl()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
ℹ With name: n1.
Caused by error:
! Result must be length 1, not 3.

The correct answer should be a vector of c(5,0.5)

I'd really appreciate help to find a solution using a map() function. I'd appreciate a description of how the solution works because i'm new to R. I need it to be generalisable as there are other functions i might want to apply in future.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data are ordered:

```
library(purrr)

examplelist |>
  map_dbl(~ max(tail(.x$week, 5)))
#  n1  n2 
# 5.0 0.5
```

`.x$week` extracts the week column from your tibble, `tail(...,5)` takes the last 5 elements of the extracted vector, and then `max` returns the largest value.

If your data are unordered by `rowcount`:

```r
library(dplyr)

examplelist |>
  map_dbl(~ arrange(.x, rowcount) |> summarize(max = max(tail(week, 5))) |> pull())
```

*Why doesn't your code work* (your code is really close to working, you are on the right track):

1. For each element you are iterating over `map_dbl` expects a single numeric value so that it can return a numeric vector. You are trying to return multiple values, hence the error:

```r
map_dbl(1:3, ~ .x + 1)
# [1] 2 3 4

# trying multiple numeric returns
map_dbl(1:3, ~ .x + 1:2)
Error in `map_dbl()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error:
! Result must be length 1, not 2.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

2. From the documentation `?map_dbl` (this also applies to many of the map functions in `purrr`), the second argument is `.f`:

> A function, specified in one of the following ways:
>
> A named function, e.g. mean.
>
> An anonymous function, e.g. ⁠(x) x + 1⁠ or function(x) x + 1.
>
> A formula, e.g. ~ .x + 1. You must use .x to refer to the first
> argument. Only recommended if you require backward compatibility with
> older versions of R.
>
> A string, integer, or list, e.g. "idx", 1, or list("idx", 1) which are
> shorthand for ⁠(x) pluck(x, "idx")⁠, ⁠(x) pluck(x, 1)⁠, and ⁠(x)
> pluck(x, "idx", 1)⁠ respectively. Optionally supply .default to set a
> default value if the indexed element is NULL or does not exist.

Generally you want to pass it a defined function (e.g., `mean`, `sum`, a user defined function), an anonymous function (e.g., `function (x) ...` not assigned to your environment), or a purrr style function/formula (e.g. `~ ...`). You are creating a purrr style function, but the issue is you are trying to pass *multiple* functions, which you cannot do. You need to combine these into a single function (don't forget to read the documentation of functions you are using. `subset` can both filter your rows and select columns!):

```r
map_dbl(examplelist,~ subset(.,rowcount > 5, select = week) |> max())
#  n1  n2 
# 5.0 0.5
```

---

One other note. I personally almost always start using `map` until I get the output I want and then I use one of the `map_` functions if I want a specific atomic vector. Also do code in incremental steps so it is easier to figure out what is causing the issue:

```r
# 1. Check that subset is filtering how I want
map(examplelist, ~ subset(.x, rowcount > 5))
# $n1
# # A tibble: 5 × 3
#   letter  week rowcount
#   <chr>  <dbl>    <int>
# 1 f          1        6
# 2 g          2        7
# 3 h          3        8
# 4 i          4        9
# 5 j          5       10
# 
# $n2
# # A tibble: 5 × 3
#   letter  week rowcount
#   <chr>  <dbl>    <int>
# 1 p        0.1        6
# 2 q        0.2        7
# 3 r        0.3        8
# 4 s        0.4        9
# 5 t        0.5       10

# 2. Add additional arguments and check output
map(examplelist, ~ subset(.x, rowcount > 5, select = week))
$n1
# # A tibble: 5 × 1
#    week
#   <dbl>
# 1     1
# 2     2
# 3     3
# 4     4
# 5     5
# 
# $n2
# # A tibble: 5 × 1
#    week
#   <dbl>
# 1   0.1
# 2   0.2
# 3   0.3
# 4   0.4
# 5   0.5

# 3. Read documentation on max function (will take max value of an entire numeric 
#    data frame/tibble, we only have one column so just the max of that column)

# 4. Confirm one numeric output per element
map(examplelist, ~ subset(.x, rowcount > 5, select = week) |> max())
# $n1
# [1] 5
# 
# $n2
# [1] 0.5

# 5. Use map_dbl to create numeric vector
map_dbl(examplelist,~ subset(.,rowcount > 5, select = week) |> max())
#  n1  n2 
# 5.0 0.5
```

Comment: Really nice answer.  Any reason to stick with formula (`~`) instead of anonymous function (`\(x)`) notation?

Comment: @andrew_reece formulas are more compact and you might consider it more canonical to the tidyverse. That being said, anonymous functions (`function(x) ...` and `\(x) ...`) are likely to be technically faster when scaled up since formulas need to be converted to functions (see `?purrr::as_mapper`), but probably not practically faster in most cases.

Comment: @andrew_reece I would also point out that I think the biggest advantage of anonymous functions is when you have nested `map` functions or variants (`map_`). Since `.x` is always the reference variable, things become ambiguous when you nest them, but this is easily remedied with anonymous functions. Nesting is not super common, but is definitely something that comes up. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48847804/6382434).

Comment: Thanks for the additional info @LMc. Re canonical, I was under the impression that the new recommendation was to always use `\(x)` over `~`.  (As in the docs excerpt in your answer, "A formula...Only recommended if you require backward compatibility with older versions of R.").  I don't have a strong opinion either way, but might suggest that, given you have that line from the docs included, it might remove a potential point of confusion for readers if your solution follows those guidelines and uses anonymous function notation. What do you think?

Comment: @andrew_reece -- great point. It is interesting because in the [purrr change log 1.1.0](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#purrr-100) the only mention is the short hand notation is now supported, but not necessarily preferred. Other tidyverse functions, like `across` make no mention of preferring the short hand anonymous functions like the documentation you reference. For now, I will leave it as is, but upvote your comment for others. Maybe in the future this will be more clear (though the documentation is clear for this example, as you pointed out). Thanks for the discussion!

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

examplelist |> 
  map(tail, 5) |> 
  map(slice_max, week) |> 
  map_dbl(pull, week)
#>  n1  n2 
#> 5.0 0.5
```